# JBAS012144 Connection timeout

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss

When I try to deploy or undeploy my application(EAR) in JBoss using Maven and Jenkins I get the following error :

```
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
[DEBUG] 
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not     
connect to remote://192.168.1.8:10099. The connection timed out
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.isDomainServer(AbstractServerConnection.java:234)
at org.jboss.as.plugin.common.AbstractServerConnection.getClient(AbstractServerConnection.java:156)
...
```

My JBoss server is listening the port 10099 (9999+100) taking into account the following jboss configuration:

```
<socket-binding-group 
    name="standard-sockets" 
    default-interface="public" 
    port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
    <socket-binding 
         name="management-native" 
         interface="management"
         port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
```

The Maven plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.Final</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
    <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
    <hostname>${deploy.jboss.host}</hostname>
    <port>${deploy.jboss.port}</port>
    <username>${deploy.jboss.user}</username>
    <password>${deploy.jboss.password}</password>
    <filename>fitness-${stage}-${app.server}.ear</filename>
    <name>fitness-${stage}-${app.server}.ear</name>
     <skip>${skip.deployment}</skip>
     <!--  Logging  ??? not working-->
      <execute-commands>
            <commands>
                 <command>/subsystem=logging/file-handler=debug:add(level=DEBUG,autoflush=true,file={"relative-to"=>"jboss.server.log.dir", "path"=>"jenkins-deployment.log"})
                 </command>
                 <command>/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as:add(level=DEBUG,handlers=[debug])
                 </command>
            </commands>
        </execute-commands>
       </configuration>                     
       <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy-application</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>                    
            <execution>
                <id>undeploying-all-application</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>undeploy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <match-pattern>fitness-.*</match-pattern>
                    <matchPatternStrategy>all</matchPatternStrategy>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>                       
</plugin>
```

With the following variables :

- deploy.jboss.host = 192.168.1.8
- deploy.jboss.port = 10099

Here is my configuration :

- OS : Ubuntu 13.04
- Java : 1.6.0_26
- JBoss : 7.1.1.final
- Maven : 3.0.3
- Jboss-as-maven-plugin : 7.6.final

Jenkins and the target jboss server are running the same machine identified by the ip 192.168.1.8

My own diagnostic :

If I run

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :10099
```

I get :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10099           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25475/java
```

And 25475 is my Jboss instance. It seems that JBoss is listening behind the right port.

I can connect using another instance with CLI :

```
sh jboss-cli.sh controller=192.168.1.8:10099
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved it setting a higher timeout value.
For example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.Final</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <hostname>${jboss.hostname}</hostname>
            <port>${jboss.port}</port>
            <username>${jboss.user}</username>
            <password>${jboss.pass}</password>
....
            <timeout>30000</timeout>
....
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Default "timeout" value is 5000ms. You can try with a higher value like 30000ms. It worked for me.

Edited:
As Pedro said, another option can be passing "timeout" to maven via a command line argument. eg. -Djboss-as.timeout=30000

Comment: Thanks. Increasing the timeout worked for me. The steps were a little different, as I'm using maven via command line with jboss-as goal. So I needed to add -Djboss-as.timeout=20000 parameter to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was JDK 7 related. My jenkins server was using Java 1.7
If you want to use the jdk 7 you need to use the following parameter :

```
-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, however the fix was different, it might help somebody. I had to change maven plugin to the following one:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Somewhat unintuitive - but this also solve the issue for me on JBoss EAP 7. Thanks!